# Manim: Why does the previous scene still remain and not transfrom with ReplaceTransform?

Tags: python, animation, manim

I've been trying to create a Manim animation where several dots are connected with lines transform as the number of points and lines increases by intervals of one.

The thing is despite using ReplacementTransform the older version of the graph still sticks around and I can't seem to get rid of it even with using .remove, .Ucreate on several different parts of the animation.

```
      
    for i in range(2, 13):
      old_fgrp = second      
      dots = []
      fgrp = second.copy()
      dts= VGroup()
      gln= VGroup()
      for j in np.linspace(-4, 4, i):
        dot = Dot(ax.i2gp(j, graph))
        dots.append(dot.get_center())
        fgrp.add(dot)
        dts.add(dot)
      for j in range(1, i, 1):
        new_dots = dots[-i:]
        ln = Line(start=new_dots[j-1], end=new_dots[j])
        fgrp.add(ln)
        gln.add(ln)
      self.play(ReplacementTransform(old_fgrp, fgrp))
      self.wait()
      # self.remove(fgrp)
      # fgrp.remove(gln)
      # fgrp.remove(dts)
      #.remove(gln).remove(dt)
```

[image: image of my code partway through, it can be observed that the previous points and lines still remain]'

Comment: Have you tried using `Transform` or `TransformMatchingShapes`? Usually they work better than other transforms and are less finicky.

Comment: It would be much better if you include a complete example that demonstrates your problem and that can be compiled.